# code coverage of CompletableFuture.supplyAsync code

Tags: java, testing, java-8, code-coverage

1. I have 10 lines of code inside  `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { }`
2. junit test case is skipping that 10 lines of code. How can i cover those 10 
   lines

```java
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        // line 1
        // line 3
        ..
        ..
        ..
       // line 10


    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Without the awareness of the actual test case. What you can possibly do to improve the code is to abstract those 10 lines of code to a method with can be then be called from the supplier.

This would give you an ease of testing the method separately without even calling the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...)` line as used in the code.

For example, consider this abstraction

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> supplyingMyValue());
```

where the `supplyingMyValue` method exists such as

```
Value supplyingMyValue() {
    // perform some logic
    return new Value();
}
```

and now you can test this method *independently*.

*Note*: The solution hereby would still not test the `supplyAsync` capability, but provide a way to test only the code invoked.

Comment: The way, you’ve written the `supplyAsync` statement, bears the same error as the OP’s code. When you don’t wait for the completion of the asynchronous operation, there is no guaranty that it will get executed during the unit test. Incidentally, the code coverage tool says the right thing; a “unit test” which doesn’t actually test the result, isn’t testing anything. It wouldn’t even notice if the operation fails with an exception. Of course, using a named method and testing the method independently would solve this too, but would make the `supplyAsync` call entirely pointless.

Comment: @Holger I do agree that the suggestion I have made would not test the `supplyAsync` execution, it was more bound towards the concern of testing the lines of code executed within it. Edited the answer to call that our explicitly.